# Problem in Uploading Sketch in Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, atmelstudio

I'm using arduino for around 3-4months. Now I'm facing issue in uploading sketch in arduino Uno.

This happened after using atmel-ice for debugging. I was trying to debug the code using atmel-ice for the first time in atmel studio. I followed tutorial video on YouTube for connecting and debugging arduino uno using atmel-ice debugger. It never started debugging it turned off with an error. After that I tried to upload sketch in board using arduino ide as well as atmel studio and using ice also but it cannot upload the sketch and in atmel studio I could read the device signature previously after trying debugging, I cannot read the device signature. I never touched the fuse settings in the atmel studio for arduino. It was default.

```
avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Users\Saurabh\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM12
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x08
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x08
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x08
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x08
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x08
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x08
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x08
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x08
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x08
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x08

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Getting above errors. in arduino ide.
I read similar issues with others some of them were saying it is in debugging mode. But after restarting it should go out of that as uno resets. I've also checked loopback it's working. This happend with my 3 of uno boards I've only 1 left now. How can I solve the issue. I tried burning boot loader also but that also got error. I think may be fuses are the issue. How can I Solve this issue.

if I'm using FTDI232 programmer it showing

```
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\\.\COM13": Access is denied.



avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

This Error.

After Trying using ftdi232 got

```
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): timeout communicating with programmer
         AVR Part                      : ATmega328P
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PC2
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : STK500V2
         Description     : Atmel STK500
         Programmer Model: Unknown
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
```

This errors.

Comment: use "Burn  bootloader" in Arduino IDE. don't upload the sketch over ISP programmer

Comment: So I tried That too: avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x04
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x04 This errors I'm getting.

Comment: do you have an ISP programmer wired to ICSP for bootloader burn?

Comment: I think ISP and ICSP are the same? If not I've Arduino board with on system programmer which I was using earlier. I've also other small programmer(FTDI232) which I'm trying to use but both of them are not working. I've also Atmel-Ice debugger but that also cannot program the arduino. I understood that the issue is with bootloader but what really I should use and how to burn bootloader.

Comment: try this https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP

Comment: Hi, I've tried doing that too but it's showing it cannot read fuses and also the signature is also not same. [github.com/Saur-Hub/testRepo ] link repo in which I stored errors. Arduino to arduino flash

Comment: the repo is private

Comment: Sorry, Now it's public please check.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that there is no input on the Tx/Rx pins then it works. I've tried this and board started working.